# ansible regexp for replace space quotes or comment

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, regexp-replace

I have a file that contain multiple row.
One of these lines may look like this:

```
item = 1000 or item = "1000" or item='1000' #with comment same line 
or item = "1000'
```

or every possible combinations regarding the spaces around the equal sign, or with single or double quotes or without quotes or, again, with or without comments on the same line.

In short, I only have to take the number and set a variable with set fact. This thing is driving me crazy.

Sorry but I don't put all the attempts I made because they would be too many.

```
myfile.conf:  
 start = 'before'
 stop=after  
 item =100  #changed  
 bool= "yes"
 class = 'first"
 author = "Scott"
```

or *item = 1000* or *item = "1000"* or *item='1000' #blalala* or *item = "1000'*
As stated above.

This is the last attempt before giving up:

```
- name: QUERY- read the myfile.conf
  ansible.builtin.shell: cat "{{ './myfile.conf' }}"
  register: resultline
  
- name: regex
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    mynumber: |-
      {{
          resultline.stdout |
          regex_search("^item *=*.*", multiline=True) |
          regex_replace(".*=*['\"](.*)['\"]*$", '\1')
      }}
```

And, of course, this not work...

```
Expected result is: 
mynumber = 1000
```

Comment: Do you want to match something like this? `(\S+)[^\S\n]*=[^\S\n]*(?:['"](.*?)['"]|(\S+))` https://regex101.com/r/XAlZfO/1 or `(\S+)[^\S\n]*=[^\S\n]*(?:['"]([^"']*)['"]|(\S+))`

Comment: Thx for your comment. I want set_fact the var mynumber with the number after the = at line that start with `item` regardless of any type of quotes, or space, tab or comment on the same line. Another problem is that the regex formula is inside the jinja construct `"{{ }}"`

Comment: ``"1000'`` and ``'first"`` should be considered the wrong syntax.

Comment: tag `python-3.x` deleted

Answer (score 1):

Given the file below. (I fixed the quotation of *class* value.)

```yaml
shell> cat myfile.conf
 start = 'before'
 stop=after  
 item =100  #changed  
 bool= "yes"
 class = "first"
 author = "Scott"
```

---

Q: ***"The var `mynumber` with the number after the `=` at the line that starts with `item`."***

A: Read the file

```yaml
    - command: cat myfile.conf
      register: resultline
```

Remove comments and create the list

```yaml
conf_list: "{{ resultline.stdout_lines|
               map('regex_replace', conf_regex, conf_replace)|
               list }}"
conf_regex: '^(.*)#.*$'
conf_replace: '\1'
```

gives

```yaml
conf_list:
  - ' start = ''before'''
  - ' stop=after  '
  - ' item =100  '
  - ' bool= "yes"'
  - ' class = "first"'
  - ' author = "Scott"'
```

Replace '=' by ': ' and create the dictionary

```yaml
conf_dict: "{{ conf_list|
               map('regex_replace', '=', ': ')|
               join('\n')|
               from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
conf_dict:
  author: Scott
  bool: 'yes'
  class: first
  item: 100
  start: before
  stop: after
```

Set the variable

```yaml
my_number: "{{ conf_dict.item }}"
```

gives

```yaml
my_number: '100'
```

The result of the evaluation `"{{ }}"` is always a string. You can convert it to an integer. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: my_number|int + 1
```

gives

```yaml
my_number|int + 1: '101'
```

---

Notes

- Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    conf_list: "{{ resultline.stdout_lines|
                   map('regex_replace', conf_regex, conf_replace)|
                   list }}"
    conf_regex: '^(.*)#.*$'
    conf_replace: '\1'
    conf_dict: "{{ conf_list|
                   map('regex_replace', '=', ': ')|
                   join('\n')|
                   from_yaml }}"
    my_number: "{{ conf_dict.item }}"
  tasks:
    - command: cat myfile.conf
      register: resultline
    - debug:
        var: my_number
    - debug:
        var: my_number|int + 1
```

- The value of the attribute *item* is an integer

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: conf_dict.item|type_debug
```

gives

```yaml
conf_dict.item|type_debug: int
```

You can use it in arithmetic operations without conversion. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: conf_dict.item + 1
```

gives

```yaml
conf_dict.item + 1: '101'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The notation of "class" is deliberately wrong because it is still possible to meet it in the presented problem. It is one of the possible cases. I mean the string I have to catch (the item number after `item =`)can appear in all the ways that I have shown, even with different quotes at the beginning and at the end. Your solution is brilliant but possible that there is no solution without converting to a dictionary?

Comment: I'm not going to solve the ``"different quotes"`` problem.

Comment: But it's work and this is awesome... you saved me from the psychiatric hospital. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, still just a little doubt: for me `var: conf_dict.item|type_debug` return `conf_dict.item|type_debug": "AnsibleUnsafeText`. without explicit `|int`casting. What's wrong?